# Eclipse - adding new WebShpere server limits JRE to 1.6(needs 1.7)

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-8

I am trying to add a new `WebShpere Server` to my `Eclipse`, steps :
`create new -> WAS v8.5 -> Configure runtime environment -> edit -> JRE for runtime environment` 
only JRE 1.6 is available.
How do I add 1.7 as JRE?

Java - version = 1.8

Thanks.

Comment: Which eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Klipper, on win 7.